# updating a file already in use

Tags: c#, image, filestream

Seen a few examples on here but they don't seem to match my senorio.

I basically have an image set as a background image using

```
if (ProductDetails.ProductBackPicFilePath != "")
{
mProdButList[i].BackgroundImage =  Image.FromFile(ProductDetails.ProductBackPicFilePath);
mProdButList[i].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
}
```

In one part of the program whilst in the management section I have other code to read the binary data from the database and create an image file to load.

```
internal bool CreateImage(string pStockCode)
    {
        FileStream fs;                         
        BinaryWriter bw;                        
        int mBufferSize = 100;                   
        byte[] mOutbyte = new byte[mBufferSize];  
        long mRetval;                            
        long mStartIndex = 0;                                

        string getImgSQL =
            "SELECT STOCK_CODE, STOCK_PICTURE " +
            "FROM STOCK_DETAILS " +
            "WHERE STOCK_CODE = '"+pStockCode+"'";

        using (FbConnection DBConn = new FbConnection(cs.ToString()))
        {
            using (FbCommand fbCmd = new FbCommand(getImgSQL, DBConn))
            {
                DBConn.Open();
                FbDataReader myReader = fbCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

                while (myReader.Read())
                {  
// ERROR HERE WHEN CREATING A NEW FILESTREAM
                    fs = new FileStream("Product Images\\product_" + pStockCode + ".jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write); 
                    bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

                    mStartIndex = 0;

                    mRetval = myReader.GetBytes(1, mStartIndex, mOutbyte, 0, mBufferSize);

                    while (mRetval == mBufferSize)
                    {
                        bw.Write(mOutbyte);
                        bw.Flush();

                        mStartIndex += mBufferSize;
                        mRetval = myReader.GetBytes(1, mStartIndex, mOutbyte, 0, mBufferSize);
                    }

                    bw.Write(mOutbyte, 0, (int)mRetval);
                    bw.Flush();

                    bw.Close();
                    fs.Close();
                }

                myReader.Close();
                DBConn.Close();
            }
        }


        return true;
    }
```

I am getting the error that the file is in use, which technically it is on another form as its displaying the picture still in the back layer.

Question is what can I do to force it to overwrite the image in use? As this works spot on if the image is not being displayed..

Comment: Make sure to add the right tag (C#?) so your question is exposed to the right people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
if (ProductDetails.ProductBackPicFilePath != "")
{
     byte[] fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ProductDetails.ProductBackPicFilePath);

     using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(fileContents))
     {
          mProdButList[i].BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms);                               
     }
     mProdButList[i].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
}
```

This does the job after hours of trying to figure a work around!

Answer (score 1):

dot net relies on windows OS functions to load and show images. windows in turn locks the image source files while it displayed. even if the image is removed from display, it might take some time to unlock the file.

one way is to explicitly call `Dispose()` on the image once it is not in use. this frees the source file.

as you said you want to show the other image while the first image is still displayed, you might consider generating the images in temp folder and as different temp files.

another (a bit odd) way is to first load the image, but before applying it as background it, clone it. the cloned image will be entirely memory backed and will not be attached to file. then dispose the source image. set the cloned image as background.

```
Image i1 = Image.FromFile(ProductDetails.ProductBackPicFilePath);
Image i2 = (Image)i1.Clone();
mProdButList[i].BackgroundImage = i2;
i1.Dispose();
```

Comment: Why I never though of `.Clone()`! I always read the file in to a `byte[]` and opened the image from a `MemoryStream`. This is FAR easier

Comment: I tried the code you provided, and was a good idea! but getting the same error for some reason. Probably because even a clone is attached to the original? :-(

Comment: looks like Image.Clone just casts the image as an object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.clone(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: even using a temp folder to hold a copy, I would end up with the same error when it came to replacing the file in use, wouldn't I? Also disposing of the image is not an option as the image always needs to be seen :-/